# New TFS 2015 Web based build definition is not cleaning artifact from previous build even after specify clean

Tags: tfs, msbuild

Building a solution with new web based build definition. passing MSBuild arguments during the build. checked clean options. but TFS is not removing old build artifacts from previous build, instead of removing an artifacts, it's giving just appending new one with old one.

using MS Build arguments:  **/p:DeployOnBuild=true /P:PackageTempRootDir=\Release /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site";DefaultPackageFileName=DemoApp.zip /p:OutputPath="$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\$(BuildPlatform)\$(BuildConfiguration)"**

I tried by changing the name of DefaultPackageFileName with something else like (**TestApp.zip**)

if I see in my output folder. I am getting both zip file created instead of one. what can be issue? [image]

Comment: Did you set the "clean" option on the repository tab?

Comment: Please create a new build definition or using another build agent to test these MSBuild parameters again? I have tested it in my build, and it delete  those files(including the DemoApp.zip) for the previous build under the path `C:\...\agent\_work\50\b\...\_PublishedWebsites\WebProj_Package`. Did you mean this path? If you refer to another path, please post here.

Comment: @DanielMann - Yes, I am setting up Clean in repository tab

Comment: @Tingting0929-MSFT - Yes, I am checking at same path as you said. I will try again and see, I am thinking, I may need to pass additional MSBuild arguments as i am changing the location of staging artifact OutputPath="$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\$(BuildPlatform)\$(BuildConfiguration) in my MSBuild arguments. it can be reason, it's not identifying that path during clean up.

Comment: @Tingting0929-MSFT - Did you tried with same MSBuild arguments?

Comment: Yes, I use `OutputPath="$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\$(BuildPlatform)\$(Bu‌​ildConfiguration)` and I set check the clean option and it delete the files under the path `C:\...\agent\_work\50\b\any cpu\release\_PublishedWebsites\WebApplication1_Package`. The **Clean** is equal to rebuild. Did your other build definition also have this issue? Did you try another build agent to have a check?

Comment: Yes, I think this issue is not with all build definitions. I created new build definition and tested it. Looks good. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. Looks like in some cases, we need to pass variable **Build.Clean** with Value **binary**. found it from https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/repository 
Thanks for response.

Answer (score 0):

According to the comment above. Please copy this build definition to a new build definition.